# Persistent Connection API availability on ASP.NET Core SignalR

Tags: .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

We use in our application the SignalR Persistent Connection API, as explained at 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr#connections-and-hubs

In current 2.1 version of ASP.NET Core SignalR we still don't see this API implemented. Is the hub model compatible and scalable as well? Any chance the persistent connection API will be available?

Answer (score 1):

Persistent connection is not available.

There is a lower layer available. Please read:
https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1528